# Replacement for "It was as if he was"

Tags: word-choice, subjunctive-mood

> It was as if he was messing around with him.

Is there an alternative for that sentence so the "double was" can be removed? I believe that it is grammatically correct, but it just doesn't flow well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, John, the second **was** should actually be **were**, so that solves your problem.

From Wikipedia (emphasis mine):
The past subjunctive form may be used similarly to express counterfactual conditions after suppose, **as if**, as though, unless, etc.

Suppose that I were there now.
She looks as though she were going to kill him.

**As if** works just like **as though** in the second example.  Problem solved.